# "tous les deux jours/toutes les cinq minutes" Comment poser la question sur la fréquence

Tags: grammaire, questions

Je sais comment affirmer que :

1. monsieur Dupont mange une pomme *tous les jours*
2. mon téléphone sonne une fois toutes les dix minutes
3. etc ...

Il me semble que pour poser la question, il est possible de dire quelque chose de similaire à la phrase suivante:

> Tous les combiens votre téléphone sonne-t-il?

Est ce correct? Comment pose-t-on une question sur la fréquence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oui, c'est une façon de le dire.

En revanche, bien qu'étant employé comme un substantif, « [combien](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/combien) » n'en reste pas moins invariable en tant qu'adverbe, c'est donc:

> Tous les **combien** votre téléphone sonne-t-il ?

En français parlé courant, on entendra souvent :

> Il sonne tous les combien [environ], votre téléphone ?

ou

> Votre téléphone sonne tous les combien ?

En français écrit ou formel, on rencontrera plutôt:

> Avec quelle fréquence votre téléphone sonne-t-il ?

ou, [plus récemment](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0%20quelle%20fr%C3%A9quence%2Cavec%20quelle%20fr%C3%A9quence&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2C%C3%A0%20quelle%20fr%C3%A9quence%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%C3%A0%20quelle%20fr%C3%A9quence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%80%20quelle%20fr%C3%A9quence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cavec%20quelle%20fr%C3%A9quence%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bavec%20quelle%20fr%C3%A9quence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAvec%20quelle%20fr%C3%A9quence%3B%2Cc0) :

> À quelle fréquence votre téléphone sonne-t-il ?

Variante:

> À quelle fréquence sonne votre téléphone ?

Comment: _c'est une façon de le dire_ comment le dire autrement?

Comment: Je pensais à la deuxième (français courant) mais elle est très similaire. Sinon, on peut aussi demander « Avec (ou à) quelle fréquence votre téléphone sonne-t-il ? » C'est plus formel et moins courant à l'oral que les précédents mais plus indiqué à l'écrit.

Comment: Merci pour cette explication très limpide. N'hésitez pas d'enrichir votre réponse si vous connaissez d'autres manières de poser la question

Comment: Pour le français parlé j'aurais plutôt tendance à dire : `À quelle fréquence sonne votre téléphone ?`. De même, `Votre téléphone sonne tous les combien ?` est plus courant / naturel.

Comment: @DRz oui, merci ! J'ajoute ces variantes.